# Read SAM file with Local File Inclusion

Tags: windows, penetration-testing

I have to hack (for learning purpose) a windows server through Local File Inclusion. I have a web application that is vulnerable to Local File Inclusion
I'm trying to include SAM file from windows/repair/SAM. But when i include the file strange symbols appear (as you can see in the pictures below).
[image: LFI Inclusion result]

How can I read the hash password in clear?

Comment: ever heard of binary ? hex editor? Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAM file is a registry hive, so you need to study and parse the registry hive file format. You can find its description here:

- https://jadro-windows.cz/download/registry-m.zip
- https://jadro-windows.cz/download/registry-pn.zip
- source code of the `chntpw` project
- Offline Registry Library (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210757(v=vs.85).aspx) – this library allows you to parse registry hive files.

I doubt the password are stored in plain text. You can find their hashes (NTLM), so you need to crack them, e.g. using rainbow tables (